# Nhibernate, Domain Model, Changes, Disconnected, Cloned (Need better title - but can't express it clearly!)

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

Sorry about the title - hopefully the question will make clear what I want to know, then maybe someone can suggest a better title and I'll edit it!

We have a domain model.  Part of this model is a collection of "Assets" that the user currently has.  The user can then create "Actions" that are possible future changes to the state of these "Assets".  At present, these actions have an "Apply" method and a reference to their associated "Asset".  This "Apply" method makes a modification to the "Asset" and returns it.

At various points in the code, we need to pull back a list of assets with any future dated actions applied.  However, we often need to do this within the scope of an NHibernate transaction and therefore when the transaction is committed the changes to the "Asset" will be saved as well - but we don't want them to be.

We've been through various ways of doing this

- Cloning a version of the "Asset" (so that it is disconnected from Nhibernate) and then applying the "Action" and returning this cloned copy.
- Actually using Nhibernate to disconnect the object before returning it

Obviously these each have various (massive!) downsides.

Any ideas?  Let me know if this question requires further explanation and what on earth I should change the title to!

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I had any NHibernate fun, but could you retrieve the Assets using a second NHibernate session? Changes made to the Asset will then not be saved when the transaction on the first session commits.

Comment: This would be fine - but we load our aggregate root that contains the Assets and Actions as entities within the aggregate via one nhibernate session and traverse the aggregate from the root to reach these objects, then call methods on them to do things.

Comment: This, IMO. Just keep in mind that NHibernate allows Sessions to be nested, and there is a behavioral difference between a "top-level Session" and a "child Session", and you'll need to know which you want if you go this route. Also be aware that this can be a slippery slope of "oh, just do it in a new Session" that can create unnecessary roundtrips and other inefficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working around a similar problem where performance was also an issue, thus it was not possible to re-load the aggregate using a secondary (perhaps stateless) session. And because the entities that needed to be changed "temporarily" where very complex, I could not easily clone them.

What I ended up with was "manually" rolling back the changes to what would be the assets in your case. It turned out to work well. We  stored each action applied to the entity as a list of events (in memory that is). After use the events could be re-read and each change could be rolled back by a counter-action.

If it's only a small variety of actions that can be applied, I would say it's easily manageable to create a counter-action for each, or else it might be possible to create a more generic mechanism.

We had only four actions, so we went for the manual edition.

Comment: For complex objects, an undo list would work well. You could even extend NHibernate via Save/Update event listeners that would throw if the undo list wasn't empty. (e.g. Force you to accept the changes or revert them before committing.) Of course the technique to use (cloning or undo) is going to be dependent on the complexity of the object graph as we both mentioned. Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could manage this with NHibernate using ISession.Evict(obj) or similar techniques, but honestly it sounds like you're missing a domain concept. I would model this as:

```
var asset = FetchAsset();
var proposedAsset = asset.ApplyActionsToClone();
```

The proposedAsset would be a clone of the original asset with the actions applied to it. This cloned object would be disconnected from NHibernate and therefore not persisted when the Unit of Work commits. If applying the actions is expensive, you could even do the following:

```
asset.ApplyProposedChanges(proposedAsset);
```

Comment: I too would do that, whenever possible. But it might not always be easy/possible to make a deep clone of a complex entity with children, grand-children and so on. I don't if that's the case here though :)

Comment: This is exactly what we are doing, but as asgerhallas says, it is not always easy/possible to make a deep clone of the object graph.

Note that my question explicitly details the two approaches we've looked at: Cloning a version of the "Asset" and Actually using Nhibernate to disconnect the object before returning it.  Your answer is exactly the same as these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [Unit of Work wrapper](http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/unitofwork.html), so you can commit or revert changes as needed.

Comment: I do have one.  Problem is that I need to make changes to the model or run business rules that are dependent on the outcome of applying the actions - all within one unit of work.  In other words: I want some changes to be persisted but not others.